# clojure recursion conj a list

Tags: recursion, clojure, functional-programming, lisp

```
((fn foo [x] (when (> x 0) (conj (foo (dec x)) x))) 5)
```

For this code, the result is [5 4 3 2 1]
Why isn't is [1,2,3,4,5]?
I see we do conf from result of recursive foo call with a value.
For I thought it should be 1 2 3 4 5?
Need help to understand this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `conj`:

> clojure.core/conj
>   ([coll x] [coll x & xs])
>     conj[oin]. Returns a new collection with the xs
>       'added'. (conj nil item) returns (item).  The 'addition' may
>       happen at different 'places' depending on the concrete type.

The termination condition of your function yields `nil`, because the test is a when. So the deepest conj call will be:

```
(conj nil 1)
(1) <-- a list
```

The next one:

```
(conj (conj nil 1) 2)
(2 1)
```

So your result will be in decreasing order because conj appends at the front for lists. If you want it in increasing order, start with an empty vector like this:

```
((fn foo [x] (if (> x 0) (conj (foo (dec x)) x) [])) 5)
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call expands to

```
(conj (conj (conj (conj (conj nil 1) 2) 3) 4) 5)
;(5 4 3 2 1)
```

The implicit `nil` returned by `(foo 0)` puns to `()`.